# H2 DB file in Docker - this database is empty

Tags: spring-boot, docker, h2

I have a basic Spring Boot app with an in-file H2 database.

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:./src/main/resources/database/db
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

This database file is pre-filled. When I start the app using `mvn spring-boot:run` I can see that the DB is not empty.

I've built a Docker image with `mvn spring-boot:build-image`, and I run it with `docker run -p 8080:8080 --rm myapp:tag`. When accessing the DB I get this in the container logs:

```
(...)
Table "XXX" not found (this database is empty)
(...)
```

It's like the container doesn't see the DB file. Why is that ?

Comment: There's an almost 100% chance that `./src/main/resources/database/db` is not pointing where you think it is, especially once you've built an image. Inspect the content of your image and you'll see there's likely no such file anywhere in there. If you actively need it as a file (and not, say, as a resource on the classpath), then you have to find a way to configure `spring-boot:build-image` to include this as an actual file.

Comment: In the container I find the file in `workspace/BOOT-INF/classes/database/`, exactly the same location as in the jar (`mvn install`), and it works fine when running `java -jar myapp.jar`. It makes me assume that the path `./src/main/resources/database/db` is only relevant at build time, not at run time.
Side question from your comment: can't it be a file AND a resource on the classpath ? What's the difference in this case ?

Comment: I assure you the path **is** relevant at runtime. I think when you run `java -jar myapp.jar` you are currently in a directory where `./src/main/resources/database/db` *happens to point to your actual file* (i.e. in the root path of your project). Try being in any other directory and using `java -jar the/full/path/to/your/myapp.jar` and you'll see behaviour that's strikingly similar to running the container image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered by @Joachim Sauer in a comment, the reason is that the path defined in `spring.datasource.url`, in this case `./src/main/resources/database/db`, is read at runtime. And, once packaged in a Docker image, this path becomes irrelevant.

In case it's useful to someone, here is how I made it work, in case the H2 DB file is `./src/main/resources/database/db.mv.db`:

1. create a new file `application-docker.properties`
2. add this property: `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:./BOOT-INF/classes/database/db`
3. build the image with `mvn spring-boot:build-image` (no change)
4. run the image with `docker run -p 8080:8080 --rm -e "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker" myapp:tag`